# How to get value of <a> in column by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<td class="left">
     <a href="#"> ABCXYZ
     </a>
</td>
```

How I can get value "ABCXYZ" of < a > in < td > in < table >?

Comment: use `.text()` like `$('.left').find('a').text()`

Comment: on which event you required?

Comment: @SandipPatel why does it have to be on an event?

Comment: `in column by javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following script for this

```
$('.left a').html()
```

Comment: `in column by javascript`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
   $(function(){
  $('.left').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).text();
    alert(val);
  });
});
```

or just

```
 var txt = $('.left a').text();
    console.log(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to get anchor tag text then:

```
$("table tr td.left a").each(function (a, b) {           
        console.log(b.text);
    });
```

If you wants to get only text then use below code:

```
$("table tr td").on('click', function (e) {        
    console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of these:

```
$('table td.left a').text();

$('table td.left a').html();
```

although I would add an id as near to the anchor as possible and use that as the selector.

Or if you had more than one you could do something like:

```
$('table td.left a').each(function() {
    var thistext = $(this).text();
    // do something with thistext
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("table tr>td.left>a").each(function (index, item) {     
            console.log($(item).html());      
 });
```